# Get twitch streamer game being played? beautifulsoup / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

How would I get the value of the game being played from a streamers stream: ? Example stream: https://www.twitch.tv/xqcow

this is the code I have now:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/xqcow')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
game = soup.select_one("a data-a-target")
print(game)
```

Comment: 1. _"get the value of the game being played_" What part of the page is this? 2. What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: @MendelG I updated my code but the game is under the title, right now it is Fall Guys: Ultimate Knockout <span class="CoreText-sc-cpl358-0 kLnQWs">Fall Guys: Ultimate Knockout</span> within the <a data-a-target="stream-game-link" hyper link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *title* is under the class `kLnQWs`.

You can use the following CSS selector:

```
game = soup.select_one("span.kLnQWs").text
print(game)
```

Output:

```
Fall Guys: Ultimate Knockout
```